# Concise way to accurately find factors of any number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The last number of $365$ is $5$, therefore I’ve been told that $5$ is a factor of $365$, which it clearly is. This however does not work for other numbers, i.e., $9$ is not a factor of $8599$.

I’ve also been told to consider the sum of the numbers, i.e., $315: 3+1+5 = 9$, and since $9$ is divisible by $3$, $3$ is a factor of $315$, which it is. But this is severely limited because it only holds if the sum is a multiple of $3$, so using this for $389$ doesn’t work because $3+8+9 = 20$, which isn’t a multiple of $3$.

With this info in mind, is there a reliable way to factor numbers using inherent properties? If there is not, I am a bit worried that I will be unable to reliably factor any given number of a reasonable size. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule

Comment: If you happen to have a quantum computer handy, you can try [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm).  But otherwise, factoring is a notoriously difficult problem.

Comment: @mfl I read that over but there is no real way to make the info into a procedure to be used for any number. I suppose a human can only factor numbers which are reasonably easy to do? Is this a fair statement? I’m worried because the GRE has factorization problems and I do not know how complex they may be.

Comment: You could start writing numbers as lists of prime factors, then it is easy. Addition might get tricky though...

Comment: Or perhaps addition is just shifting the list of all numbers left, forgetting values that get shifted out.

Comment: I found prime bags: arXiv:1104.3056 perhaps they can be useful.

Comment: Without electronic help, only trial division and perhaps methods using quadratic residues are the usual tools used to factor a number. In rare cases, Fermat's method (finding two squares with difference equal to the given number) is effcient. For harder cases, electronic help will be needed to get a result in a reasonable time. The most spectacular factorization managed by hand was probably the factorization of $2^{67}-1$ , but it took the Sundays of three years.

Comment: With electronic help, numbers upto $80$ digits can be factored quite quickly and small factors (upto $30$ digits) can also be found relatively fast even for very large numbers. There was made tremendous progress but still factoring is a hard procedure in general.

Comment: For reasonable small numbers , lets say, upto $10^4$, trial division is enough for hand calculation. You only need to divide by the primes and you can stop when the remaining number is smaller than the square of the largest prime you already checked, assuming you check the primes in increasing order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81693/discussion-between-peter-and-emil).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can find plenty of similar divisibility rules in [this Wikipeida article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule).

> With this info in mind, is there a reliable way to factor numbers
>   using inherent properties? If there is not, I am a bit worried that I
>   will be unable to reliably factor any given number of a reasonable
>   size.

You are right to be worried, since factoring numbers is a hard problem. This is especially true for large integers with a small number of large prime factors. A good example are semiprimes, i.e., large integers $n=p_1\times p_2$ with exactly two very large prime components $p_1$ and $p_2$.

In fact, integer factorization is so hard, modern cryptographic methods rely on them.